# cypress can't verify server running on localhost even though I can see it in browser and have instituted a wait check for localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localhost, cypress

I'm attempting to adapt [this example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-docker-compose) to my own environment, which very closely mirrors this codebase, but getting a:

```
cypress      | Cypress could not verify that this server is running:
cypress      | 
cypress      |   > http://client
cypress      | 
cypress      | We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your baseUrl.
cypress      | 
cypress      | Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.
cypress      | 
cypress      | We will try connecting to it 3 more times...
cypress      | We will try connecting to it 2 more times...
cypress      | We will try connecting to it 1 more time...
cypress      | 
cypress      | Cypress failed to verify that your server is running.
cypress      | 
cypress      | Please start this server and then run Cypress again.
```

given this docker-compose.yml in the root:

```
client:
    image: graceland/client_dev
    networks:
      - allhosts
    volumes:
      # this is where our code is mounted into the running container
      - ./client/:/client
      - ./shared/:/client/src/shared-copied # see shared-copied.md
    working_dir: /client
    command: yarn start
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
e2e:
    #image: "cypress/included:10.6.0"
    image: "cypress"
    build: ./e2e
    container_name: cypress
    depends_on:
      - client
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://client
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "-t","30","http://localhost:3000", "--", "npx","cypress","run"]

    volumes:
      - ./e2e/cypress:/app/cypress
      - ./e2e/cypress.config.js:/app/cypress.config.js
      - ./e2e/wait-for-it.sh:/app/wait-for-it.sh
```

and this `cypress.config.js` in the `/e2e` folder:

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3000",
    supportFile: false,
  },
});
```

any idea what's going on here? Running this on my local machine with `docker-compose up` - and I can see `http://localhost:3000` in my browser.

Comment: `http://client:3000`?

Comment: nope. Maybe something about using a port in the baseURL?

Comment: Here: `command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "-t","30","http://localhost:3000",` it definitely cannot be localhost if you want to wait for the client to be ready. This needs to be `client:3000`. Also: `CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://client` looks like missing the port, unless you also have something running on port 80

Comment: @mheavers Nope what? It says that cypress is trying to connect to `http://client` but it should be connecting to `http://client:3000`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your e2e service `command` and `cypress.config.js`

They both should refer to the host as `client` not `localhost`

Since you expose the client service to port 3000 on your host machine it is expected that you can view it on your browser using `localhost`

But from the `e2e` service point of view, the localhost refers to the e2e service container localhost. To which no process is listening there.

Containers in your compose file are discoverable through their service name, that's why you need to refer to `client`

Comment: Seems like for whatever reason I can't reference "client" - `environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://client:3000` - results in `Cypress could not verify that this server is running` . Also - I am able to remove baseUrl entirely from `cypress.config.js` and everything works (as long as I'm referencing http://localhost:3000. Is there a reason to have it in both places?